# How to smart limit the trash size/quota?

Tags: trash, quota

I am talking about the `.Trash-1000` folders like.

Some times it's contents size reach like 18GB, and applications trying to write files will fail with no clear messages, because the disk space has ended.

I am looking for a way to force a trash quota/limit with some extra constraints.

These constraints options would be good:

- by file date/time, older files are erased first.
- by available disk space, if it has like less than 1GB, no matter what trash file datetime it is, it gets erased to keep 1GB available.
- by file size, if trashed file is bigger than 500MB, it is promptly erased.

Is there such software sitting somewhere so I can avoid scripting it up?

Answer (score 2):

Try autotrash from the repositories.

> autotrash — program to automatically purge old files from the
>   FreeDesk-top.org trash

Once installed, you'll need to add a cron job to run autotrash.
Run `crontab -e`, and add the following line:

```
@hourly /usr/bin/autotrash --keep-free 1024 -d 30
```

I don't think it covers the last point, but it's something to start with.

PS: Also check out `man autotrash` for more info.

Comment: interesting, I think it will do! I actually want to keep the max amount of trash possible, but always have good disk free space, still testing it thx!

Comment: I think it works but it is unnecessarily slow. I sat here waiting something happens for about 5 min on a 3GB trash folder and nothing happened. It uses python, I think a more simple script using this answer in a loop with a work step of 100 entries would provide a much faster result: http://superuser.com/a/552606/157532